# Regex word search with apostrophe

Tags: javascript, regex

```
highlightStr: function (body, searchString){
    console.log(searchString);
    var regex = new RegExp('(' + searchString + ')', 'gi');
    console.log(regex)
    return body.replace(regex, "<span class='text-highlight'>$1</span>");
}
```

Above is the code I'm using.  I want to find and replace the searchString, which could be anything. It works fine for most words, but fails when finding words with apostrophes.

How can I modify the regex to include special characters like the appostrophe.

```
var body = "<br>I like that Apple&#x2019;s.<br>";
var searchString = "Apple's";
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want `var regex = new RegExp(searchString + "(?:'s)?", "gi");`? Note you do not need the outer parentheses. Besides, it is a good idea to [*escape*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) the `searchString`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: It works just fine - https://jsfiddle.net/0jgsayk9/

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear about the problem. I rewrote the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [*escape*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) the search string to make sure the regex works OK even if the search string contains special regex metacharacters.

Besides, there is no need wrapping the whole pattern with a capturing group, you may always reference the whole match with `$&` placeholder from the replacement pattern.

Here is an example code:

```js
var s = "I like that Apple's color";
var searchString = "Apple's";
var regex = new RegExp(searchString.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "gi");
document.body.innerHTML = s.replace(regex, '<b>$&</b>');
```

Comment: I tried this.  It will find and replace "Apple" with highlighted.  But, doesn't work for "Apple's"

Comment: @JasonGelinas It is still unclear. What value holds `Apple's`? What is the input string? What is the expected result? You can see that my `searchString` holding `children` finds and replaces `Children's`.

Comment: The searchString = "Apple's".  The body = "I like that Apple's color".

Comment: See update: it works. Now your question sounds much more unclear than at the beginning though.

Comment: I found out why it wasn't working on my end.  In the body, the apostrophe is escaped. So it's not "Apple's" instead, it's "Apple&#x2019;s".  Any ideas on how to modify the regex to pick this up?

Comment: @JasonGelinas You should perform the search and replace on plain text, not its entitized representation. Else, entitize the search string, too.